# Using Processing's loadImage in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, processing, processing.js, loadimage

I am using the [Processing API](http://processingjs.org/reference/) to draw an image to my HTML canvas, which I can use later in the code. The JavaScript code that I have is:

```
var sketchProc = function(processingInstance) {
  with (processingInstance) {

    /* @pjs preload="images/hot-air.png" */

    size(innerWidth, innerHeight);
    var testImage = loadImage("images/hot-air.png");

    draw = function() {
      image(testImage, 0, 0, 500, 500);
    }
  }
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var processingInstance = new Processing(canvas, sketchProc);
```

The console says that the image has dimensions 0x0. I tried loading with [Processing's directives](http://processingjs.org/reference/pjs%20directive/), but I am still getting an image dimensions of 0x0. However, when I call `loadImage()` inside the draw loop, the program recognizes the image's dimensions of 512x512.

I do not want to continuously call `loadImage()` inside the draw loop. What should I do to make sure that the image loads properly outside the draw loop?

You can find a minimal working example [here](https://repl.it/@DanielHong/Testing-ProcessingJS).

Comment: Your code snippet is not correctly formatted, and it shows an error when I try to run it. Please fix the code snippet to properly include Processing.js, or just post it as text instead of as a runnable snippet.

Comment: I have edited my post to show where I put the directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, thanks for posting an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to play with.

I believe the problem is that, for some reason, the preload directive, and maybe the `loadImage()` function itself, doesn't work when you're writing [JavaScript-only Processing.js code](http://processingjs.org/articles/jsQuickStart.html#javascriptonlyprocessingcode). I've tested this in various editors and versions of Processing.js.

So it appears that to use the `loadImage()` function, you should use [pure Processing code](http://processingjs.org/articles/jsQuickStart.html#writingpureprocessingcode). [Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XVjQGR) is a CodePen that shows how you'd do that:

```
<script type="application/processing">
    /* @pjs preload="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3a/Cat03.jpg/1200px-Cat03.jpg"; */
    PImage testImage;

    void setup(){
      size(500, 500);
      testImage = loadImage("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3a/Cat03.jpg/1200px-Cat03.jpg");
      println(testImage.height);
    }

    void draw() {
      background(100);
      image(testImage, 0, 0, 250, 250);
    }
</script>
<canvas> </canvas>
```

Just for comparison, [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GyjLLe) is the same code using JavaScript-only syntax. This doesn't work.

But taking a step back: if you're comfortable using JavaScript, then why are you using Processing.js? Processing.js is designed for Processing (Java) developers who want to write Java syntax that's automagically converted to JavaScript. At this point Processing.js is pretty old and no longer maintained.

Instead, I'd recommend using [P5.js](https://p5js.org/). P5.js allows you to write JavaScript syntax to create web-first Processing sketches. P5.js is much newer and is still being actively developed.

Here is the same code in P5.js:

```
var testImage;

function preload(){
  testImage =  loadImage("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3a/Cat03.jpg/1200px-Cat03.jpg");
}

function setup() { 
  createCanvas(400, 400);
} 

function draw() { 
  background(100);
  image(testImage, 0, 0, 250, 250);
}
```

Shameless self-promotion: I wrote a tutorial on the differences between Processing, Processing.js, and P5.js available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/p5js/which-processing).

Comment: @DanielHong Please post a [mcve] showing exactly what you tried with the preload command so we can copy and paste it to run it ourselves.

Comment: Where should I put the preload command? I tried putting it inside the "with" block and didn't get anything. I am suspecting that what the documentation suggests only works in the Processing Sketchbook.

Comment: @DanielHong It definitely works in the browser as well. My guess is that it's a symptom of how you're wrapping your sketch code in a function. If you have a CodePen or JSFiddle, I'd be happy to play with it.

Comment: Thank you for your willingness to help! I will see what I can do. Are you okay if I put my entire project up or would you prefer a minimal working example?

Comment: @DanielHong If at all possible, you should try to put together a **minimal** example that shows the behavior you're seeing in as few lines as possible. But the example should be complete enough that it shows the problem.

Comment: I will post my code somewhere public and link you and other visitors to it once I do so.

Comment: You can find an MWE at https://repl.it/@DanielHong/Testing-ProcessingJS. I will put that in the original post too so that other visitors can see it.

Comment: I really like your solution. I prefer writing pure Processing code, so I will use your solution. I wrote JavaScript because I felt that it would be more web-compatible. I really appreciate your time in looking into this.

Comment: @DanielHong Shameless self-promotion: I wrote a tutorial on the differences between Processing, Processing.js, and P5.js available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/p5js/which-processing).